# What is the maximum length for a property value in Subversion?

Tags: svn

I'm about to start creating an 'executable library' by specifying a great many references in the `svn:externals` property. Before doing this, I wanted to check if a Subversion property name is restricted to a particular length, so that I don't overrun the limit after several hours' work. But I can't find anything like this in the documentation or on the Web.

So, is there a maximum length for a Subversion property value, and if so, what is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no real limit (may be 2Gbyte on 32 bit systems).
However keep in mind that PROPERTIES are not diffed, so each change in a property will add up a full new copy of this property content to the next revision.
So for propertys you can easily in 10 to 100 kb (I did this already!) So for externals this should be enough